# JNA: java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access Fortran DLL

Tags: memory, dll, fortran, jna

Fairly new to JNA but getting Invalid memory access for trying to link a Fortran dll.

The fortran code:

```
FUNCTION OpenFile(FileName,LenFileName) RESULT(Stat)   
INTEGER,INTENT(IN) :: LenFileName
CHARACTER(LEN=LenFileName),INTENT(IN) :: FileName
INTEGER :: Stat

!Set the level of messaging to error and warning messages only
CALL ZSET('MLEVEL','',0)

!Set an unconnected unit number for the file
CALL ZSET('UNIT','',1111)

!Open file
CALL ZOPEN(IFLTAB(:,iOpenFiles+1),FileName,Stat)

iOpenFiles             = iOpenFiles + 1
cFileNames(iOpenFiles) = FileName
END FUNCTION OpenFile
```

The interface:

```
public interface test extends com.sun.jna.Library {
    test reader = (test) Native.loadLibrary("test.dll", test.class);

    int OpenFile(String FileName, int LenFileName);
}
```

And calling it using this:

```
int ret = test.reader.OpenFile(fileName, fileName.length());
```

Error Im recieving

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:383)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.OpenFile(Unknown Source)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JNAerator util to provide apriori correct method mappings.